# Searching text file for string only on single line

Tags: python-3.x, search, text

In my program, I have a list of id numbers in a separate text file, one id per line. I'm using an if statement to search to see if a specified id number is already in the text file. While the chances are small, I'd like to implement something to prevent it from finding a string contained within multiple lines. Question: How do I ensure a search for id = 11223 yields a result from line 3 and not line 1/2? Including a simple example below- new to this so any other tips are greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
searching_for_id = "11223"
id_list = open('id_nums.txt', 'a+')

if searching_for_id not in open('tweet_id.txt').read():
    print("Adding to list")
    id_list.write("\nNew id")
else:
    print("Already in list")
```

---

Sample id.txt File

12383**11**

**223**5869

12**11223**

---

Side note: Most of the numbers are not already in the text file, hence the *not* statement being the "true" result. Not sure if that's bad coding practice, but thought having a majority of the program go to the else statement would take longer?

Comment: Did my solution answer your question? Let me know if it did not. Please accept the answer if it did.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to read the file and convert it to a list of integers, and then check if a given id already exists.

```
file_ids = [int(line) for line in open('tweet_id.txt').readlines()]
```

Now you can safely do:

```
if searching_for_id in file_ids:
   print("id already exists in file")
else:
   print("id doesn't exist in file")
```